# Is it possible to have multiple AuthenticationProcessingFilter on the same path in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is it possible to hock multiple AuthenticationProcessingFilter(s) on the login path in spring security? lets I want to have the following filtrates run in order every time user login:

requestIntegrityFilter: validate the url/hostname/IP/.. according to some rules
 secretTokenAuthenticationFilter: validate token generated in the browser from 3rd party. 
 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : validate username/password

I could have one AuthenticationFilter where I can encapsulate all this logic in one method.but I'm wondering if there are any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple Filters, just specify the order and you are fine

```
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

This command will make sure of execution of the subsequent filters in the filter chain